# In Unity Editor 2019.4.29f1, a java file uses or overrides the deprecated API when I attempt to build Android Project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and not familiar with it.

I am using Unity Editor 2019.4.29f1.
When I create a new empty project with Unity Editor 2019.4.29f1 which is named to TestProject_27
(Shown in the following figures. Figure 1.) and build an Android Project, I met these errors. The first of the error tells me that the file

```
"C:\Unity\TestProject_27\Packages\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java"
```

uses or overrides a deprecated API.
(Shown in the following figures. Figure 2.b)

Figure 2.a depicts the build settings to build an Android project.

Figure 1 (project_list_version_1.png)
project_list_version_1.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szmuW.png)

Figure 2.a (build_screenshot_1.png)
build_screenshot_1.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tby4N.png)

Figure 2.b (depreciate_API_2.png)
depreciate_API_2.png
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGtEY.png)

According to the error message, I compile the file with -Xlint option with java compiler.
(
I typed the command in the DOS cmd prompt.
javac -Xlint
"C:\Unity\TestProject_27\Packages\unityLibrary\src\main\java\com\unity3d\player\UnityPlayerActivity.java"
).
(
The file UnityPlayerActivity.txt is attached to the Attached Files area. Sorry, I dont upload a .java file
(See the following P.S. 1 for the reason)
)
I got these errors. Then I export the content in DOS cmd prompt into a text file, named it as "java_in_unity_error_2.txt".

According to the error messages, some android packages are missing.
I don’t know why they are missing.

---

P.S.
1:
The reason why I uploaded "UnityPlayerActivity.txt" instead of "UnityPlayerActivity.java" is
.java ext file is NOT allowed in Unity Forum.

2:
The reason why I dont upload the .7z file that contains all files of this project (named TestProject_27) is
the .7z file is too large (over 1024 KB) even though I had zipped it with 7-zip manager.

---

Extra NOTE:
1:
When I close and open the Unity project (named TestProject_27), then build Android project again.
Then the issue dispear. (However, there are other issues. I will create other thread to discuss these issues)

I dont know why. I think it is very strange. I hope anyone can give me explanation.

---

Any replies or solutions about this issue will be appreciated.

Sorry for my poor English. My English may be poor since I am not a native speaker in English.

Thank you for reading.

---

zipped file:

All things about this issue (including the screenshot of Error message and whole project etc)

are zipped into these files which are available at Google Drive.

[zipped file](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1o48dtZjm-TBSmx02EcffCrKCXFSeI02w)

1. Get more details about the error message.
   (Such as compile with -Xlint option with java compiler)
2. Google it.
3. Create a post in Unity forum.

Link:
[issue in Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/a-java-file-uses-or-overrides-depreciated-api-in-unity-project-with-unity-editor-2019-4-29f1.1434028/)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your debug keystore is broken, I recommand you to create your own keystore to sign your app in the [Android player settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#Publishing) -> Publishing settings. You can follow this documentation: [Android keystores](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-keystore.html). If you prefer the debug keystore, you can simply delete the broken file, it will be regenerated next time you build the app.

By the way the error you think is actually a note.